# select one item in an outlet collection - swift

Tags: swift, uibutton, iboutletcollection

How would I code: select the button who's titlelabel.text is equal to "category"

```
@IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!

var category: String?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewdidload()

      //I want to put the code here!

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can [`filter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter) out that button

```
let requiredButton = buttons
        .filter{ $0.titleLabel?.text == "category" }.first
```

Also you can achieve that with [`first`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1848165-first)

```
let butt =   buttons.first(where: { $0.titleLabel?.text == "category" })
```